# symfony how to "wildcard everything" route

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I want to create a route in Symfony in the following ways: `/admin/_api/*` and `/admin/*`. So, overall I want to have a configuration like the following:

```
/admin/_api/users
/admin/_api/posts
/admin/_api/comments
/admin/_api/* -> (AdminBundle:Error:api)
/admin/*  -> (AdminBundle:Error:html)
```

Based on the given configuraiton, if a user goes to `/admin/_api/test`, the router will dispatch to `ErrorController::apiAction`. If a user goes to `/admin/users` it will dispatch to `ErrorController:htmlAction`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

maybe try it with requirements, in routing.yml:

```
...
all your routes that should match first
...
admin_api_wildcard:
  pattern:  /admin/_api/{wildcard}
  defaults: { _controller: AdminBundle:Error:api }
  requirements:
      wildcard: .*
```

in newer symfony-versions `pattern` is replaced by `path`:

```
...
all your routes that should match first
...
admin_api_wildcard:
  path:  /admin/_api/{wildcard}
  defaults: { _controller: AdminBundle:Error:api }
  requirements:
      wildcard: .*
```