# It is possible to auto translate routing in Symfony 5?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I have on my controller the following route:

```
#[Route('/{_locale<en>}/profile', name: 'profile_en', methods: 'GET')]
#[Route('/{_locale<es>}/perfil', name: 'profile_es', methods: 'GET')]
```

It is possible to have all my urls translateds (in this case profile) in a file and do something like that for example?

```
#[Route('/{_locale<%app.supported_locales%>}/profile', name: 'profile', methods: 'GET')]
```

*This should give me all possible locales + profile url translated*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [symfony how to "wildcard everything" route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33958113/symfony-how-to-wildcard-everything-route)

Comment: No sorry, I'm looking for translate the url profile somehow so I don't have to write it every time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since symfony 4.1 they have internationalized routes (a.k.a. Localized Routes)

- Docs → https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#localized-routes-i18n
- Announce → https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-internationalized-routing

Quick-preview:

```yaml
# config/routes.yaml
about_us:
    path:
        en: /about-us
        nl: /over-ons
    controller: App\Controller\CompanyController::about
```

Since you already use `_locale` and in your case with php-attributes it should be:

```php
#[Route(path: [
        'en' => '/profile',
        'es' => '/profil'
    ], name: 'profile', methods: 'GET')]
```

I think, that's exactly what you're looking for.
But **untested**, since I have no way to play with php-8 right now

P.S. You could also rename your route to `profile_i18n` so each time you (or other devs) use it, you immediately know → it's an internationalized one